Can a Forcecage be destroyed with brute force?
Forcecage states that a creature cannot leave the cage by non-magical means. It also says it can't be dispelled by dispel magic. However, it doesn't say anything about disintegrate.
To me, this implies that it can be destroyed. I know I can't leave the cage by non-magical means, but can I make the cage leave me with non-magical means?
Like, can I break it down with my battleaxe and then push it away from me, thus making the cage leave me?
Alternatively, can I forcefully break it down with a spell like thaumaturgy by screaming loud enough with the volume increase to shatter it? Because Path of the Giant barbarian doesn't really have movement spells, at least not that I know, and the fairy race doesn't give teleportation or movement spells either.

I think my answer here is relevant, particularly the diversion on the (nonexistent) rules for walls (though the question is not a duplicate): https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/194921/40516

No. The spell does not give any means for destroying the cage, and states explicitly that you can't escape using non-magical means (cutting down the cage is also a form of escaping).
Compare that to something like Wall of Stone or Wall of Ice, which both explicitly explain

that they can be destroyed
how to do so

A Forcecage is meant to be indestructible. The only thing that can break one is a spell or ability that explicitly mentions it, such as like Disintegrate.
(But it would have been clearer if they just said so outright, the way that Wall of Force states that it is "immune to all damage". )

So if I'm put in a Forcecage, all I can do is wait for it to go away on its own?

You might note that “immobile” is equivalent to “indestructible”.

@Tasi Depends - you could teleport out, or if it is the version with bars, change in to Gaseous Form and seep out.

@NobodytheHobgoblin are either of those available to a path of the giant fairy barbarian?

@Tasi Not as a class or racial feature unless you took a feat like Fey Touched, which would give you misty step. But if you are small enough (I think you are 4 inch tall now?) and it is the cage form, you might be able to wriggle and squeeze out through the 1/2 inch gaps between the bars.

@NobodytheHobgoblin is there any good thing about the cage form that would compel an enemy to choose that over the box, or should I expect it to just always be the box?

@Tasi Yes, the cage is larger than the box, and thus can capture larger creatures (or several smaller ones). You also likely can shoot in with arrows, to risklessly kill a creature in there that has no ranged attacks it can use.

@NobodytheHobgoblin "if you are small enough [...] you might be able to wriggle and squeeze out through the 1/2 inch gaps between the bars" -> Wouldn't that count as "leaving [the cage] by non-magical means"?

@Walen, You are right, there would need to be some magical effect supporting it the way the spell is written. For example, if they use reduce to become smaller and fit through, or if they use a spell like fly that gives them a new form of movement magically.

Can a Forcecage be destroyed with brute force?
Only by breaking the rules, too.  The rules don't provide an option for destroying the force cage by brute force.
Is it possible?  Anything's possible.  For instance, If you're 30 strong, and hit it with the Axe of the Gods and a 9th level divine smite (or whatever), perhaps the DM would allow it.  Sometimes DMs do crazy things.
But, by the rules?  No.
I know I can't leave the cage by non-magical means, but can I make the cage leave me with non-magical means?
Yeah, you can't get out.  It says:

A creature inside the cage can't leave it by nonmagical means.

But seriously?  If your character is actually small enough to be able to fit through the 1/2 gaps between the bars, say, 4 inches tall, then it's at least worth a question to the DM.  Spell effects need adjudication all the time.
Strictly by the rules, yeah, you're stuck.  But strictly by the rules, you can't be a 4-inch high PC.  So ask the DM.
Like, can I break it down with my battleaxe and then push it away from me, thus making the cage leave me?
Not by the rules.
You'd need a very special battleaxe.
There's a battleaxe in the adventure Waterdeep: Dragon Height named Azuredge that has an interesting property:

You gain a +3 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon. The shield spell provides no defense against the axe, which passes through that spell’s barrier of magical force.

Note that this is a sentient legendary weapon, forged by an archwizard and sworn to protect its city; it's a one of a kind, you can't just pick one up at a weapon shop.
However, if you had a battleaxe with a somewhat similar property, that destroyed spell effects made of magical force, you'd be in business.  No such battleaxe exists that I know of, but it's possible within the rules of the game.  And, it's very common for DMs to make up magic items.  So, up to the DM.
But within the rules of the game, you're not getting through the forcecage with your battleaxe or any other battleaxe.
BUT, there are weapons, just not battleaxes . . .
The Forcebreaker Weapon
The forcebreaker weapon, from The Book of Many Things1, says:

This weapon was crafted to destroy structures made of force, such as those created by Forcecage or Wall of Force.  Striking a Large or smaller structure of magical force with this weapon automatically shatters that structure.

It says it can be "any weapon that deals bludgeoning damage", and battleaxes deal slashing, so, by the rules it can't exist as a battleaxe, but it is an example of a weapon that can destroy a forcecage.
Ruinblade
Ruinblade is a legendary and unique greatsword, possessed by  Moghadam, the architect of the Tomb of Horrors, from the Infernal Machine Rebuild adventure.  It has a property called Destructive Ruin:

Destructive Ruin. You can cast the disintegrate spell from the weapon, but can target only a nonmagical object or a creation of magical force.

These weapons show that there are weapons that can destroy a forcecage within published materials.  A DM could choose to include such a weapon, or a weapon with similar properties.  Are you likely to get such a weapon?  Probably not, and even more probably not at low levels.  At higher levels?  It's possible.  High level campaigns often include powerful magic items.  Completely up to the DM, though.
Alternatively, can I forcefully break it down with a spell like thaumaturgy by screaming loud enough with the volume increase to shatter it?
I like the resourceful thinking, but definitely not.  Since there's nothing in the rules that says that sound destroys a forcecage, then, by the rules, sound doesn't.  Even if it did, three times louder doesn't seem very loud, certainly not loud enough to break a 7th level spell.
Could there by other such weapons?
Teleporting
You said:

Because Path of the Giant barbarian doesn't really have movement spells, at least not that I know, and the fairy race doesn't give teleportation or movement spells either.

There are lots of ways to teleport.  Of course, one way is to be a spellcaster with the spell.  Other ways include magic items or feats.
Teleportation, by any means, can be unreliable for escaping a forcecage, since you have to make a charisma saving throw to teleport out, so you might need multiple tries; on top of that, it doesn't tell you the DC, so it might be really hard.
Magic items
As an example, the helm of teleportation is a magic item that allows you to teleport.
There could be other magic items that allow teleportation.
Feats
The Fey Touched feat from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything grants, among other things, the ability to cast misty step once per day.
There's another feat, Fey Teleportation, from Xanathar's Guide to Everything, that also allows you to cast misty step, although, unfortunately, it has a prerequisite of "Elf (high)".
You will eventually get out
The spell only lasts for an hour, though.  So, eventually, no matter what, you'll get out.  Of course, someone might be waiting to do something awful to you, but you can be waiting to do something awful to them.  My money's on the barbarian.

1 - The Book of Many Things is a supplemental book.  It's introduction says:

Welcome to The Book of Many Things, whose twenty-two chapters give you character options, magic items, spells, monsters, ready-to-play adventures, DM advice, and setting elements designed to be dropped into your own campaign.

A DM would have to choose to use the book and drop a forcebreaker weapon into a campaign.  It's not a crazy stretch that a DM could retool it as a slashing weapon and make it a battleaxe.

Also, about the part where dms make up magic items, my DM already did that for me. I'm a fairy, meaning I'm affected by some things my teammates aren't affected by, such as turn the faithless, so I have a bracelet of resistance, which gives me advantage on rolls against affects originating from a teammate that are not specifically intended by said teammate to affect/hit me. The exact description of the item is "Whenever you roll a saving throw against an effect originating from a teammate not explicitly targeting you, roll with advantage."

And because of that, it might be unlikely for me to get another custom magic item, because that one seems pretty good.

Yeah, well, anything can happen.  I had a wizard, by the time the campaign was done at 20th level, she had magic items with her name in them, more than one.  She had a flying pony, too, but that's another story.

Yeah, but it'll probably be a while before I get another custom magic item at least, because we're still level 3 for now, and I'm definitely not getting a magic item to counter 7th level spells for a while

5e does not specify
The game does not specify if objects made out of force have HP and can be damaged, or not.
As an experiment, reword it to replace "magical force" with "solid stone":

An immobile, invisible, cube-shaped prison composed of solid stone springs into existence around an area you choose within range. The prison can be a cage or a solid box as you choose.

[... snip ... ]

A prison in the shape of a box can be up to 10 feet on a side, creating a solid barrier that prevents any matter from passing through it and blocking any spells cast into or out of the area.
[... snip ...]
A creature inside the cage can't leave it by nonmagical means. If the creature tries to use teleportation or interplanar travel to leave the cage

[...snip...]

The cage also extends into the Ethereal Plane, blocking ethereal travel.


This spell can't be dispelled by dispel magic.

The key sentence here is "A creature inside the cage can't leave it by nonmagical means."  Even with "magical force" replaced with some other noun (solid stone, iron, paper), that clause still applies.
Now, an interesting question becomes, what happens if the person has a magical battle axe?  Hitting the cage with a magical axe to hack a hole seems like a plausible "magical means".
Traditionally, D&D has ruled that things made of "magical force" are indestructible, but nothing in the 5e rules states this.  It would be perfectly consistent with the rules for a DM to give objects made out of "magical force" some HP value, invulnerabilities, resistances, etc.
There are three spells that create magical force that are often used this way: Force Cage, Wall of Force and Tiny Hut.
Giving the Force created by these 3 spells a HP value and resistances doesn't really break the game.  You could give them a reasonably large HP value, so they aren't useless spells, and lots of resistances, because it makes sense that constructs made out of magical force shouldn't be insulted to dust.
An example of a possible DM ruling:
Resists: Acid, Cold, Fire, Lightning, Necrotic, Thunder
Immune: Radiant, Poison, Psychic, damage from nonmagical weapons
AC: 25
HP: 50 HP per spell slot level per 5' x 5' section.
With such a ruling, a Barbarian could hack their way out of the cage.  The Force Cage would have 350 HP, a Tiny Hut would have 150 HP and a Wall of Force would have 250 HP.
(Wall of Stone, a 5th level spell, makes 180 HP panels; these Walls of Force are significantly tougher with additional AC and immunities.)
But that kind of thing is up to your DM.
(My logic: Magical Force objects are often transparent, so radiant doesn't harm them.  As objects, Psychic makes little sense.  And they have no biology to poison.  We make them immune to mundane weapons, and resistant to pretty much all magic (except other magical force).
25 AC means that even magical weapon attacks on them tend to be deflected - only a solid blow by a skilled wielder can contact and not be deflected.
50 HP per slot level is large enough that it exceeds the HP of other constructs at similar slot levels (like wall of stone), and high enough that wasting that much damage from a foe feels like a real victory (a 8th level spell that states "the next 400 damage target does is reduced to 0, no save" would be a good spell), but low enough that it isn't pointless to try when trapped.)
In previous editions of D&D
In 3e, the wall of force and forcecage spells were explicitly immune to all damage.
Most people will default to that assumption, but 5e doesn't include that clause.
